# What is the process for calculating the percent canopy of these 2 layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, landsat, satellite

I am attempting to create a table that shows the percent of canopy per census district in arcgis pro. The data is in two different types. The first is a census tract shape file and the other is high resolution satellite data. The satellite imagery is 35 raster files that have been vectorized. The resulting table for each file shown n-number of polygons of various areas that have a discrete assignment of either 1 for "canopy" or 0 for "no-canopy". The end result should be a table that has columns of "CENSUS TRACT, AREA, PERCENT CANOPY, AREA CANOPY". [image: screenshot showing census table]

Below is the census table. Id like to append the Percent canopy to this table...

This table is the canopy. The column 'gridcode' represents canopy cover

[image: screenshot of canopy]

I don't have a whole lot of experience with GIS, So I hope what I'm asking makes sense. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Use the [Union](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/union.htm) tool to answer this question.

Comment: You will need to calculate the area of the census tract before the union https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm, remove the 'no vegetation' polygons, calculate the new areas or the union then using summary statistics https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm (statistics field: new area-SUM and census area-MAXIMUM, case fields of unique ID for your census tracts) get the sum of the 'has vegetation' from the union, to get the percentage divide *new area sum* by *census area* X 100.